# Find the similarities between two files

Tags: bash, awk

I have two file like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

and a file with two columns

```
1 0.11
2 0.12748
5 0.45
12 0.48
7 0.48
8 0.7
13 0.78
14 0.88
```

I would like to find thesimilarities between the two files. If the in both files the number in file 1 apper also in the first column of file 2 then it means that there it must appear in the output file. The output should be:

```
1 0.11
2 0.12748
5 0.45
7 0.48
8 0.7
```

I tried with different combination of grep but it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}$1 in a' test.1 test.2
```

Note in an array the lines appearing in the first file, then print lines in the second that were in the first. Lines will appear in the output in the order they appear in the second file.

Or join:

```
join <(sort test.1) <(sort test.2)
```

The files need to be sorted. Lines will appear in dictionary order.

Comment: +1 @Kevin. one question though, I have seen some using `a[$1]++` and some just `a[$1]`. Is there a benefit of using one over the other?

Comment: The difference is that `a[$1]` creates an empty entry, so later `$1 in a` statements will test true but `a[$1]` will test false; `a[$1]++` will cause both `a[$1]` and `$1 in a` to test true. So when using `$1 in a` there is no practical difference, but `a[$1]` will be different.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `grep -f patt_file file` to get the patterns from a file. That is, search in `file` patterns included in `patt_file`.

See the output with your given input:

```
$ grep -w -f file1 file2
1 0.11
2 0.12748
5 0.45
7 0.48
8 0.7
```

From `man grep`:

> **-f FILE, --file=FILE**
>
> Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line. If this option is used multiple times or is combined with  the  -e  (--regexp)  option, search for all patterns given. The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.

Comment: Is their a difference between your answer and `grep -w -F -f`? I always use second one as it seems to be quicker.

Comment: To be honest, I am not quite familiar with `-F`, so I don't know :)

Comment: Not sure if `the number in file 1 apper also in the first column of file 2` is being completely met. This would pull lines where second column has value `1,2,3..4 etc`. Not sure if OP has that kind of data so if he thinks its good then my +1 still stands.

Comment: Hi @Jaypal, as I have the `-w` for word and 2nd column is like `X.YY`, it will not match lines incorrectly `0.44`. Anyway, @Kevin's answer is safer so it's the one I would use :)

Comment: @fedorqui I agree with you. Based on OP's data this answer is right one from the problem. However, no harm in playing safe.