# compare 2 files in unix by key column

Tags: shell, unix

we are looking key column "name"

file 1 is

```
id|name|age|sal

1|AAA|30|2000

2|BBB|40|3000

4|CVC|32|2000

5|DDD|25|2000
```

file 2 is

```
name

FFF

GGG

AAA

DDD

RRR
```

output would be as

file 3 (Maching)

```
id|name|age|sal

1|AAA|30|2000

5|DDD|25|2000
```

file 4 (not maching)

```
id|name|age|sal

2|BBB|40|3000

4|CVC|32|2000
```

Please give me output using Unix

Thank for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the similarities between two files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028128/find-the-similarities-between-two-files)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the awk filter for this

```
    $ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){++a[$1]}
        END{for(i in a){print i" "a[i]}}' file1.txt 1.txt 2.txt
    put 1
    get 1
    move 2
```

Where:

- `FNR==NR{a[$1];next}:` when processing `file1.txt`, we mark the
  occurence of `$1` in associative array `a`.
- `($1 in a){++a[$1]}:` when processing `1.txt` and `2.txt`, we check
  if `$1` is existed in associative array `a`, if yes, increasing the
  count by 1.
- Finally, loop through associative array `a`, print the key (first
  field in files) and its value (number of ocurrences in `1.txt` and
  `2.txt`).

Refer to :
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125762/compare-first-column-in-different-files

Comment: Do not copy paste answers from other sites without even mentioning: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125768/ NOTE: the final link was added after my comment. You should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing